# How to localize Nuxt's form validation error messages using vee-validate

Tags: nuxt.js, vee-validate, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I am struggling with localizing form validation in NUXT.jS using `vee-validate`. There is very small documentation about NUXT in vee-validate official docs. I wonder if I can localize error messages using vee-validate.

Everything is working fine. i18n plugin, vee-validate plugin. But I am not being able to put these two together.

My `Vee Validate` setting

```
import { extend } from "vee-validate";
import { required, alpha, email } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";

extend("required", {
  ...required,
  message: "This field is required"
});

extend("alpha", {
  ...alpha,
  message: "This field must only contain alphabetic characters"
});

extend("email", {
  ...alpha,
  message: "This email field must contain a valid email address"
});
```

I tried [this](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/examples/i18n.html#localize-api) from official documentation but nothing yet.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `configure` of `vee-validate`

```
import { extend, configure } from "vee-validate";
import { required, email, min } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";
import { i18n } from "./i18n";

configure({
  defaultMessage: (field, values) => {
    // override the field name.
    values._field_ = i18n.t(`fields.${field}`);

    return i18n.t(`validation.${values._rule_}`, values);
  }
});

extend("required", {
  ...required,
  message: "This field is required"
});

extend("alpha", {
  ...alpha,
  message: "This field must only contain alphabetic characters"
});

extend("email", {
  ...alpha,
  message: "This email field must contain a valid email address"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want dynamic localization I have written an article about this. [Here you can read it](https://medium.com/js-dojo/connect-i18n-and-vee-validate-nuxt-js-i18n-and-vee-validate-works-greate-together-d086edd4ca22).